# How can i list the certificates for a web app?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to list the certificates for a specific web app and am using the following command:

```
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group
                      [--query-examples]
                      [--subscription]
```

But this is for a resourcegroup but what if the resourcegroup has more than 1 app.
HJow can i just get it for a specific app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell to get certificates for a specific WebApp using command:

```
Get-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" -WebAppName "<WebAppName>"
```

[image]

AZ CLI command below does not have WebApp name in the output, so it cannot be filtered by `--query` parameter

```
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group
                      [--query-examples]
                      [--subscription]
```

[image]